# How can I obtain the IP address of a user filling out a Cognito Form?

Tags: cognito-forms

I would like to determine the IP of a user that is filling out my Cognito form.

How can I find out this information?

Answer (score 2):

To look up the IP address of the person submitting a form:

1. Add a Calculation field
2. Set Calculation to `=Entry.Origin.IpAddress`
3. Set Show This Field to Internally

Comment: Nadia, this is a nice answer on what was kind of a crummy question.  As such, I have reopened the question.  If you see this kind of situation where the question is of poor quality but answerable, it would be awesome if you would suggest an edit on the question so that it doesn't get swept under by the system.  Thanks for attending to the Cognito questions!